How to set the password for the Posgres 16.X with Docker 25.0.X?
Sounds like the basic skill, however it looks like the Docker's and/or PosgreSQL's API has pretty changed, so many command I have googled does not work anymore. Thus let us begin from versions list.
Version list
Client: Docker Engine - Community

 Version:           25.0.4
 API version:       1.44
 Go version:        go1.21.8
 Git commit:        1a576c5
 Built:             Wed Mar  6 16:32:12 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

About Posgres, for the postgres image, it should be latest one for the April 2024, namely 16.2.
docker-compose.yaml
Most likely, the frontserver service does not matter for this topics, but I have left it just in case.
version: "3.5"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Production-Database
    ports: [ "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}" ]

    environment:

      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    volumes:
      - DatabaseData:/data/example.jp

volumes:
  DatabaseData: {}

The Postgres required POSTGRES_PASSWORD environment variable, but Docker detects the .env file, so I have referred to DATABASE_PASSWORD environment variable.
.env
Assume that the correct password is ACTUAL_PASSWORD.
DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_NAME="STAGING"
DATABASE_HOST="Database"
DATABASE_PORT="5432"
DATABASE_USER_NAME="postgres"
DATABASE_PASSWORD="ACTUAL_PASSWORD"

Docker command
sudo docker compose up --build

Connection attempt
Because my application must be run on VPS, the host is not the "localhost" - it must the IP address of the VPS which I can not share.
Trying to connect with ACTUAL_PASSWORD:

Output:
Example-Production-Database     | 2024-04-07 01:08:24.202 UTC [93] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
Example-Production-Database     | 2024-04-07 01:08:24.202 UTC [93] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"

Maybe the password has not been set correctly?
Unfortunately, if to try default pass1234, nothing will change.
What have I missed?


Don't forget about if there are exist a database already in the volume (DatabaseData in your case) at the moment you have running the container, then POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, and POSTGRES_DATABASE parameters will be ignored.
In other terms you can not change login and password (using POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD) and can not create a new database (using POSTGRES_DATABASE) after database initialization is done, it's possible only before database initialization (when the database is not exist, at first run).

So make sure you are not starting your container on already existent volume.

@RabbanKeyak Thank you for the advice. Before each experiment, I am execute sudo docker system prune -a then remove all volumes by sudo docker volume rm [VOLUME_NAME1] [VOLUME_NAME2] ... [VOLUME_NAME_N]. Because according the sudo docker volume list no volumes remaining, I suppose, I am following your advice.

good if it so, one less problem.

The POSTGRES_PASSWORD environment variable is used to set the password.
I don't have access to any information for your front_server service, but I'll substitute a test service that will connect to the database.
version: "3.5"

services:
  Database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: Example-Production-Database
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d postgres -U ${DATABASE_USER_NAME}"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  test:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - PGPASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    command: sh -c "psql -h Database -U ${DATABASE_USER_NAME} -c 'SELECT * from pg_user;'"
    depends_on:
      Database:
        condition: service_healthy

The test service will connect to the database and then run the SELECT * from pg_user; query.
An important aspect of this setup is that the test service waits for the database to be "healthy". And the database in turn will only be "healthy" when it is ready to accept connections. This is important, otherwise the test service will try to connect before the database is ready. My hypothesis: this is the problem with your existing stack.
In the screenshot below you can see:

(top panel) connection to database from the test service and
(bottom panel) connection to database from the host (using same password as specified in the .env file).



Thank you for the answer! I'll check your solution tomorrow, but now I need to inform you that I have tried the connection from the local PC (my screenshot is about it). I suppose, If normal connection from the local PC does not work, it will be unable to connect from the front_server. Also, I'll append the FrontServer.Dockerfile on which front_server refers.

With the setup I have provided you will be able to connect from both the host machine (your "local PC") and the other Docker Compose service. Please try my setup and verify that it works for you. Then we can change to using your original front_service.

Sorry for keep you waiting. I have removed the front_server from docker-compose and repeat the experiments. Also, I have added the health check to my docker-compose.yml and then got the same output as in your screenshot.
Unfortunately, I still could not connect with the database from local PC by the IP address of the VPS, 5432 port, postgres username and password which I could not publish. What I need to check next?
Maybe postgresql.conf matters? I have succeeded with similar connection in another VPS without touching of postgresql.conf before, but maybe API has changed...

With this setup you should be able to connect from the host using psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres. The database host is 127.0.0.1 (it's running on localhost), so this is the IP that you should be connecting to. Are you trying to connect from the same machine that's running the Docker Compose stack?

I have tried to run this command and got "password authentication failed for user 'postgres'" error with both actual password specified in .env and default one (pass1234). Hmm, what it could be? It is not enough just to specify the POSTGRES_PASSWORD in docker-compose.yml. Or, if the password includes the forbidden characters, why no error has been emitted?

I have found the cause. It was just forbidden characters in the password, but no error has been emitted. Also, looks like the allowed characters
is not documented. According this, the following characters not allowed: %, &, @, +, ^. My password has non of them, but has -, ~, *, #, ', _, |, !, and>.
O'K, thank you for the help. I have accepted and upvoted your answer.
